# how to run PlaySound() function with an string array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, playsound

I am trying to get words from a text file and play sounds of those words. I am, somehow succesfull coding the first part but not that sucessful when it comes to play *.wav format sounds.
I do get words from text file and add them into a string array. but I could not manage to use PlaySound() function with that array. here is the code

```
i = 0;
    while (i < count) {
        cout << "now playing:" << str[i] << endl;
        i++;

           bool played = PlaySound(TEXT("-.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
           cout << "played ?" << played << endl;

    }
```

All i want to do is replace that "-.wav" with my current str[i] index. The indexs are 4 words for now. Can-You-Hear-Me. These words must be in playsound function. I hope my eng is clear enough. Thx

Comment: `PlaySound(str[i], NULL, SND_SYNC);` doesn't work? How about `PlaySound(str[i].c_str(), NULL, SND_SYNC);`? Notes: You'll want to move `i++;` to after you last use `str[i]` and `TEXT` doesn't work on variables, so if `str[i]` isn't the right type of character you'll either have to change which version of `PlaySound` you're using, try `PlaySoundA` or convert the string to wide characters.

Comment: What @user4581301 observed could be fixed with a `for` loop. `for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) { ... }` - The `i++` then happens after every execution of the loop body.

Comment: @user4581301 I used .cstr() and it works perfect for now. And i ll correct my loops. I have spent some time with Playsound() but i could not found any useful manual for it. I hope u have some resource and i appreciate it.

Comment: `PlaySound` is a Windows function. When I'm looking for information on a windows function I'll search for *MSDN <name of function>*, MSDN being the Microsoft Developer's Network, where Microsoft used to stash all of their documentation. It still works because the first link that came back is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85).

Comment: @user4581301 sorry but seem like i could not solve my problem. I thought it is solved when compiled with no error but...   EDİT: it work with PlaySoundA function. Thx again